# Запись результатов функции в файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, функции, текст

```
def finder(strng, ch, start = 0):
    index = start
    count = 0
    while index < len(strng):
        if strng[index] == ch:
            count += 1
            if count == 4:
                if strng.find('Второй') != -1 or strng.find('Second') != -1:
                    f.write(strng[:index] + '2;' + strng[index+1:])
                else:
                    f.write(strng[:index] + '1;' + strng[index+1:])
                return strng
        index += 1
    return -1

file = 'C:/temp/1.txt'
with open(file, "r+") as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i >= 5:
            f.writelines(finder(line, ';'))
```

Нужно считать файл до 5 строки и начиная с нее выполнять функцию, которая должна проверять строку и записывать значение в зависимости от условия.
И вот запись у меня не получается. Сейчас строки дописываются в конец файла, а не заменяются.

пример файла:

```
Заголовок1
Заголовок2
Заголовок3
Заголовок4
Первый;Второй;Третий;;;1;00;;
Первый;;Третий;;;1;00;;
;;Третий;;;1;00;;
```

в итоге в файле должны получить:

```
Заголовок1
Заголовок2
Заголовок3
Заголовок4
Первый;Второй;Третий;2;;1;00;;
Первый;;Третий;1;;1;00;;
;;Третий;1;;1;00;;
```

Comment: Я правильно сделал правку кода? В следующий раз сами оформите код. Разделите код на считывание из файла и на запись в файл. И в finder явно передавайте переменную файла

Comment: Кст, для считывания из файла используйте `open(file)`, для запись `open(file, 'w')`. И можете в вопросе добавить саму задачу, содержимое того файла и что должно получиться.

Comment: @gil9red извините не совсем понял что Вы исправили?

Comment: Форматирование вашего кода в вопросе. Отступы съехали и код стал неисправным. Для сравнения: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/832149/revisions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, понятно будет по комментариям.

```
def finder(line, f, ch=';', start=0):
    index = start
    count = 0
    while index < len(line):
        if line[index] == ch:
            count += 1
            if count == 4:
                if line.find('Второй') != -1 or line.find('Second') != -1:
                    f.write(line[:index] + '2;' + line[index+1:])
                else:
                    f.write(line[:index] + '1;' + line[index+1:])
                
                return line

        index += 1

    return -1


# Открываем и считываем строки
with open('1.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# Открываем для записи (можно и в 1.txt записать)
with open('2.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(lines, 1):
        if i < 5:
            # Пишем заголовки в файл
            f.write(line)
        else:
            finder(line, f, ';')
```

---

**PS.** Мне кажется, что алгоритм функции `finder` можно улучшить, но т.к. не знаю точного предназначения ее, то не стал этого делать